# Osgi annotation processing

Tags: java, annotations, osgi

I have a component declared using the @Component annotation, in which there is a set of methods that implement communication with another api, in my product there are operations that are prohibited for a user with an anonymous id. I want to create an annotation, for example @ProhibitedForAnonym, which, every time the method is called, will check the ID of the anonymous customer, with the ID in the method parameter and throw an error if the IDs match. But I don't understand how to do annotation processing in OSGI, maybe some kind of interceptor?

Answer (score 1):

There is no general interception framework in OSGi. However, you could do interception in the following ways:

1. Don't. Personally, I feel that since we've lambdas a code-based solution has won hands on over a 'magic' annotation check. It is about the same number of characters but a lambda based call allows me to single step, provide context to the security check, does not suffer from the `THIS` problem, is testable, and requires no complex framework with lots of bug opportunities.
2. Use the [byte code weaving support in OSGi](https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/7.0.0/framework.weavinghooks.html). You need to register a weaver early and then weave any class that has these annotations. You can take a look at https://github.com/aQute-os/biz.aQute.osgi.util/tree/master/biz.aQute.trace for an example of how to use the byte code weaver. Make sure your weaver is there first. If you use bndtools you can add it to the -runpath to run before anybody else. Or use start levels.
3. Use proxying. You can 'hide' and original service with the Service Hooks and then register a proxy. In the proxy you can then do the annotation check. This also requires that this code runs first and cannot be updated. I think the [spec](https://docs.osgi.org/specification/osgi.core/7.0.0/framework.servicehooks.html) has an example of this

You might want to read: https://www.aqute.biz/appnotes/interceptors.html